# Referência da função

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber o porquê da função do objeto estar referenciando para o name de fora do objeto, e não para oque está dentro do objeto? o certo não seria a função procurar a variável que esta mais próxima do escopo da função?

```js
const obj = {
    name : 'nome1',
    age : 21,
    funcaoObj () {
        return name
    }
}
 
name = 'name2'

console.log(obj.funcaoObj())
```

Answer (score 4):

Você está acessando o escopo da função `funcaoObj`, porém, como não foi encontrada ela sobe um nível para o escopo global, o objeto em si não possui um escopo como se fosse uma Classe.

Para acessar internamente deveria ser algo do tipo `return obj.name`. ou usar `function`

```js
    function meu_objeto(){
         this.name = "name1";
         this.age = 21;
         this.funcaoObj = function(){
            return this.name;
         };
    };
    
    name = "name2";
    var teste = new meu_objeto();
    console.log(teste.funcaoObj());
```

Comment: então devo presumir que as variáveis que se encontra dentro de uma função são "caçadas" dentro de escopos ?

Comment: É algo chamado de Registro de Ativação de Escopos, um conceito de linguagem de programação e compiladores.

Answer (score 0):

O `name` é uma variável do `window`. Uma vez que você altera o valor, ela terá sempre esse valor até que você feche a janela.

Ao abrir a janela novamente, o valor de `name` é *null*. Quando você seta um valor a ela, essa variável terá sempre esse valor enquanto a janela estiver aberta.

```js
name = "nome2";
console.log(window.name);
```

Depois de setar um valor ao `name`, der um refresh na página e executar o código abaixo, sem fazer nenhuma atribuição a `name` terá o resultado:

```
<script>
// name = "nome2" comentado
console.log(name); // imprime "nome2" no console
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso você queira retornar o `name` do seu objeto e não da variável do `window`, teria que fazer desta forma, adicionando um `this`:

```js
const obj = {
    name : 'nome1',
    age : 21,
    funcaoObj () {
        return this.name
    }
}
 
name = 'name2'

console.log(obj.funcaoObj())
```